# How can I handle click notification by using cordova-plugin-firebase push notifications?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I used cordova-plugin-firebase to make a push notification in my Ionic 1 application.

When I used this function (onNotificationOpen) the action on it done when the device received the notification not when click on it.

```
window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  alert("the notification recieved ")
}, function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

How can I handle the click notification?

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried?

Comment: window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(data) {
             
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    alert("the notification recieved ")

                }, function(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });

Comment: Could you please show the notification body where you are sending the notification.

Comment: I send the notification from php server 
`code`$message=array(
            
            'title'=>'Hllow',
            'body'=>"mesage from server",
           
//            
             
        );
        $fields = array//
            (
                'to' => "device-token",
                'data' => $message,
                
               
            );